# Python log viewer with GUI?

Tags: python, gui, log, logging

I'm looking for some `python` log viewer where I can filter logs based on their level.

I've found only one thing: [Logview](https://pythonhosted.org/logview/) which would be great but links are dead and I didn't find it anywhere else.

Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cutelog](https://github.com/Busimus/cutelog) is a great choice in your purpose. It's not what you described though.